# First order reaction

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics

I am little bit confuse about relating the half life time period of a first order reaction something like

$$\ce{2A -> B + C}$$

Here the rate of reaction will be half of the rate at which $\ce{A}$ is used up.

$$\text{Rate of reaction} = k[\ce{A}]$$

$$\text{Rate of disapperance of}~\ce{A} = 2k[\ce{A}]$$

Integrating it half life will be $\displaystyle\frac{\ln 2}{2k}$.
Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: It is absolutely correct.

Comment: Is there something else you are confused about?  Your math may be correct, but you seem to be implying that there is a problem with your answer.

Comment: Am I being obtuse here but $\ce{A+A\to \cdots}$ is a second order reaction, not a first order one which would be $\ce{A\to\cdots} $. You can also calculate the half life of a second order reaction.